# Changing order of matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

In matlab I have a set of matrices e.g. ([1,2;3,4],[5,6;7,8],[9,10;11,12]) and I want to change the order of them e.g. ([5,6;7,8],[9,10;11,12],[1,2;3,4]), can I get some help into doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow please post all your approaches/attempts. This allows the community to be the most helpful. Any relevant code would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your matrices are stored in a cell `C`, e.g.,

```
C = {[1,2;3,4],[5,6;7,8],[9,10;11,12]}
```

you can use the following code to reorder the matrices

```
C([2,3,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Collection Of Matrices Stored in Cell Arrays:

If the matrices are stored in a cell array you can reorder them by indexing. Here the reordered matrix is stored in cell array `Matrix_2`. The result can be set to the original by: `Matrix_1 = Matrix_2`.

[image: Cell Array Reordering]

```
Matrix_1 = {[1,2;3,4],[5,6;7,8],[9,10;11,12]};
Matrix_1

Matrix_2(1) = Matrix_1(2);
Matrix_2(2) = Matrix_1(3);
Matrix_2(3) = Matrix_1(1);
Matrix_2
```

### Collection is a Set of Concatenated Matrices:

Similar to the previous indexing used for the cell arrays you can index the two dimensional matrix by its rows and columns. The numbers neighbouring the colon `:` signifies the range of cells to take from `start:end`.

[image: Reordering Concatenated Matrices]

```
Matrix_1 = [[1,2;3,4],[5,6;7,8],[9,10;11,12]];
Matrix_1

Matrix_2(1:2,1:2) = Matrix_1(1:2,3:4);
Matrix_2(1:2,3:4) = Matrix_1(1:2,5:6);
Matrix_2(1:2,5:6) = Matrix_1(1:2,1:2);
Matrix_2
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**